# I am looking for a 2X extender for a Canon 100mm EF 2.8 (non L series)

Tags: extension-tubes

I have a Canon 100mm EF 2.8 Macro lens (not an L series) for my 70D.  I want a 2x extender, but am not sure what to get that will fit and work.  I have not seen a 2x for a non L lens.

Comment: I would typically consider a "2x extender" to be a teleconverter, however you've used the tag for extension tubes, which is something different. Can you clarify what you want and/or your intended use/goal?

Comment: Canon refers to their teleconverters as "Extenders".

Comment: @Mary Anne Wilmouth - What do you wish to photograph with a 2x extender plus your 100mm f/2.8 lens?

Comment: Are you looking to use the extender (teleconverter) to increase macro magnification, or to use the lens as a 200mm telephoto at normal focus distances?

Answer (score 1):

Canon's own teleconverters (which they for some perverse reason call "extenders") will only fit a limited number of long L lenses, as the teleconverter has a protrusion in front which has to fit into a similar recess at the rear end of the lens. This means that you can't use a Canon teleconverter on the Canon macro.

The good news is that there are third-party extenders that you can use. Not the Sigma ones as they have a protruding bit just like the Canon, but the Tamron/Kenko/Whatever (basically one and the same product, rebranded) are flat at both ends and will work.

(The usual caveats apply as to whether it is actually a good idea to hang a 2x converter on a given lens. But it will work. You will get 200mm f/5.6 lens-converter combination, probably best used at f/8-f/11 to regain some of the sharpness and contrast lost to the teleconverter.)

Comment: You'll also increase the maximum magnification by 2x, which can be handy for a macro lens. If the use case is just to gain reach then the same money would be better spent on a longer lens.